# How to send Traditional chinese character message from Java to IBM MQ

Tags: java, character-encoding, ibm-mq, mainframe, cjk

**Application scope:** To send message from java application to IBM MQ, which is consumed by non-java mainframe application

**Issue:** Simplified chinese characters message are successfully consumed and processed by non-java mainframe application. Whereas Traditional characters msg fails with below error in receiving application.

```
0051963 MQ Request failed.  MQ Type: MQGET    MQ Name: LOADER   CC: 00000001 RC: 00002079
0051963 MQ Request failed.  MQ Type: MQOPEN   MQ Name: ERROR    CC: 00000002 RC: 00002035
0051963 MQ Request failed.  MQ Type: MQPUT    MQ Name: ERROR    CC: 00000002 RC: 00002019
```

Error code 2079 say’s truncated message was accepted so message failing in receiving application.

> Why does traditional character message are truncated first? What is
> the correct encoding or CCSID should be used in java while handling
> with chinese characters?

Using below MQ jar's in java application:

```
<!-- MQ Jars -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Java Code to post message to IBM MQ.

```
Integer charSetId = 935;
        String senderQ = "queue:///"+queueName+"?CCSID="+charSetId+"&targetClient=1";   
        jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(false);              
        jmsTemplate.send(senderQ,new MessageCreator() {              
         public javax.jms.Message createMessage(javax.jms.Session session) throws JMSException {            
             TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();          
             try {
                msg.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_CHARACTER_SET, charSetId);
                msg.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_UNMAPPABLE_ACTION, "REPLACE");
                msg.setText(txt);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(errorLog.getErrorDetail(e), e);                
            }
             
            return msg;         

         }
     });
```

Comment: How long is your MQGET buffer? Traditional Chinese characters are likely 2 or even up to 4 bytes per character so you need a longer buffer to get the message.

Comment: @MoragHughson Thanks for your reply. We don't have control over receiving applications buffer size. Is there a way to specify the maximum message buffer size while posting msg to MQ? FYI current IBM MQ maximum message length is 20,00,000

Answer (score 2):

> 0051963 MQ Request failed.  MQ Type: MQGET    MQ Name: LOADER   CC:
> 00000001 RC: 00002079

Reason code of 2079 (MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_ACCEPTED) means that you need to use a larger buffer for the MQGET.

> 0051963 MQ Request failed.  MQ Type: MQOPEN   MQ Name: ERROR    CC:
> 00000002 RC: 00002035

Reason code of 2035 (MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED) means that the UserId you are connecting with to the queue manager does not hae permission to open that particular queue.  Get the MQAdmin to set the permissions for the UserId, so that it can open the queue.

> 0051963 MQ Request failed.  MQ Type: MQPUT    MQ Name: ERROR    CC:
> 00000002 RC: 00002019

Fix the security issue then this error message will go away.  Someone isn't properly coding their application because the exception (RC of 2035) should have been caught and not continued with putting of a message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We don't have control over receiving applications buffer size. Is there a way to specify the maximum message buffer size while posting msg to MQ? FYI current IBM MQ maximum message length is 20,00,000

Comment: Did the MQAdmin update the channel's maximum message length to be at least 20MB?  Note: It would be best to set it to 100MB (max value).  Also, you need to have the MQAdmin fix your UserId permission issue.